# Using $lookup in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

I have the following collections in **mydb** database:

- **purchases**: it contains documents in the following format:

  ```
  {
   _id: <ObjectId>,
   name: <String>, //customer name
   purchasedItems: <Array>
            0: < Object >
                i_name: <String> // item name
                qntity: <Int>
            // other objects in the array
  }
  ```
- **sales**: it contains documents in the following format:

  ```
  {
   _id: <ObjectId>,
   i_name: <String>,
   qntity: <Int>
   cost: <Int>
  }
  ```

I'd like to output a new collection that contains the following documents:

```
    {
     _id: <ObjectId>,
     name: <String>,
     cost: <Int>
    }
```

Where **name** is the name of the **customer** in the purchases collection and **cost** is the cost of **ALL** the items that he purchased.

Formally, each item's cost is defined as:

> purchases.purchasedItems.qntity/sales.qntity) * sales.cost

WHERE purchases.purchasedItems.i_name=sales.i_name

and **cost** in the output collection is the sum of all the items' cost.

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
db.purchases.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$purchasedItems"},
    {$lookup:
        {from:"sales",
        localField:"purchasedItems.i_name",
        foreignField:"i_name",
        as: "n_cost"}
    },
    {
        $group:{
               _id: "$_id",
               name: "$name",
               cost: {$sum: {multiply:[{$divide:["$n_cost.qntity","$qntity"]},"$n_cost.cost"]}}
        }
    },
    {$out: "results"}
])
```

I'd appreciate any help with what I did wrong and what's the correct way to do it.

Comment: what is your mongo version ?

Comment: @Veeram I'm using MongoDB 3.6

Comment: Try using `name:{$first:"$name"}`

Comment: I get null on the name field and 0 on count after using name:{$first:"$name"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are couple of things incorrect here.

Bunch of missing reference and missing `$unwind` after `$lookup` stage.

Try

```
db.purchases.aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$purchasedItems"},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"sales",
    "localField":"purchasedItems.i_name",
    "foreignField":"i_name","as":"n_cost"
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$n_cost"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id",
    "name":{"$first":"$name"},
    "cost":{
      "$sum":{
        "$multiply":[
          {"$divide":["$purchasedItems.qntity","$n_cost.qntity"]},
          "$n_cost.cost"
        ]
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$out":"results"}
])
```

Without `$unwind`

```
db.purchases.aggregate([
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"sales",
    "localField":"purchasedItems.i_name",
    "foreignField":"i_name",
    "as":"n_cost"
  }},
  {"$project":{
    "name":1,
    "cost":{
      "$sum":{
        "$map":{
          "input":{"$range":[0,{"$size":"$purchasedItems"}]},
          "as":"ix",
          "in":{
            "$let":{
              "vars":{
                "purchase":{"$arrayElemAt":["$purchasedItems","$$ix"]},
                "sales":{"$arrayElemAt":["$n_cost","$$ix"]}},
                "in":{
                  "$multiply":[
                    {"$divide":["$$purchase.qntity","$$sales.qntity"]},"$$sales.cost"
                  ]
                }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$out":"results"}
])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried the solution with the unwind option and it works!